# mongodb giving error not master with replication not initalized

Tags: mongodb

Installed a fresh instance of mongodb 3.6 on Ubuntu 16.x

While creating user mongo is giving error as `Error: couldn't add user: not master`

also same error with `show dbs`

```
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "not authorized on admin to execute command { listDatabases: 1.0, lsid: { id: UUID(\"f9e0590a4-b20a-b21b9eecf627\") }, $db: \"admin\" }",
    "code" : 13,
    "codeName" : "Unauthorized"
}
```

Replication is not enabled

```
{
    "info" : "run rs.initiate(...) if not yet done for the set",
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "no replset config has been received",
    "code" : 94,
    "codeName" : "NotYetInitialized"
}
```

Why this mongo instance is behaving like slave when its not configured to do so.

I have added hosts entries for other slave instances but not initialised them yet.

Comment: There are no slaves in replica sets, there are secondaries among other node types. Your messages indicate your server is not a primary nor a standalone which is consistent with an uninitialized RS member.

Comment: @D.SM what could be the solution ? should i initialise first before creating the user?

Comment: I suggest following the published documentation.

Comment: @D.SM can you share the link ?